# Next Js Image Component When to Use

Tags: next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

I just had a quick question about the Nextjs image component and when to use it. Currently, I am using it everywhere I have an image on my website, but Vercel just started charging which is costing me a good chunk of change. Where would be the best places to remove the image component and replace it with the html img? Does it make a different whether the image is in the public folder or if its being pull from storage?

Any advice is much appreciated as I am trying to cut some costs.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not cache the images through a CDN? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache- 1.8k

Comment: Vercel bills by unique images, so caching wouldn't fix my issue I think. https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/image-optimization

Comment: Right - each unique image processed, right? So if you cache it, it processes once until the cache is invalidated. I'm not super savvy on the next/image component, but you may want to look into it just to be sure.